# Jquery pips как установить кастомное число пипсов?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

есть слайдер

```
<div id="deposit-time" data-min="92" data-max="400" data-step="1" data-vals-pips="92,184,368,400">

var calculate_time = $('#deposit-time');
var valsPips = $("#deposit-time").attr('data-vals-pips').split(',');
$('#deposit-time').slider({
  range: "min",
  min: parseInt(calculate_time.attr('data-min')),
  max: parseInt(calculate_time.attr('data-max')),            
  step: 1,
}).slider('pips', {
  rest: 'label',
  labels: valsPips
});
```

Никак не получается добиться результата, что бы пипсы были те, которые указаны в атрибуте data-vals-pips, но при этом был кастомный шаг для самого слайдера из data-step. Помогите пожалуйста !

Answer (score 0):

степ должен быть 92, потому что у тебя ход не 1, а 92 и нужно указать values и в доке все есть с примерами

```
$('#deposit-time').slider({
  range: "min",
  min: parseInt(calculate_time.attr('data-min')),
  max: parseInt(calculate_time.attr('data-max')),            
  step: 92,
  value: valsPips[0]
}).slider('pips', {
  rest: 'label',
  labels: valsPips
});
```

Comment: так в том и дело, что мне нужен шаг 1 , и значения пипсов - конкретные из дата аттрибута, подобных слайдеров много, значения приходят с бэка

Comment: так а обновить options, где изменить step и labels и обновить pips? то есть взять аттрибуты и заменить